# can I buy moneypak card on someone else's behalf?

Tags: united-states, money-transfer

What all information is needed when you buy a greendot moneypak prepaid card at Walmart in the US. Can I buy it for a friend using cash (not a credit card or something) and just give her all the card information so she can load it to her paypal?

Comment: **Which** moneypak card in **which** store in **which** country? In its present state, your question is unanswerable, and in any case, it is best directed to the company which issues the moneypak card or the store where you are buying it rather than here.

Comment: @DilipSarwate greendot moneypak prepaid card at walmart in usa.

Comment: Probably. It's just cash-equivalent, after all.

Comment: Just on the off chance this applies: These Greendot Moneypaks have [had some *scams* associated with them](http://www.nerdwallet.com/blog/current-events/fraudsters-scam-victims-green-dot-moneypak-card/). And prior to that they were being used in a hacking fraud scam where a virus took one's computer "hostage" and claimed they were the FBI and required a moneypak order to release the computer or else "face the consequences"!  So, please make sure everything is legit before you part with your real money.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can put cash on a moneypak card for your friend to load on paypal.

> No personal information to share and no forms to fill out in store
>   source: https://www.moneypak.com/Partner/CashDepositHowItWorks.aspx

Loading cash onto a Paypal account is explicitly listed as a common use of the card.
source: https://www.moneypak.com/AboutMoneyPak.aspx?Tab=1